# tslint creating error but functionality wise its working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, tslint

- I am new to tslint and typescript.
- I am trying to fix this error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- i did some research but not able to find solutions.
- providing code below.

**(no-typeof-undefined) app/components/sports.ts: Avoid typeof x === 'undefined' comparisons. Prefer x == undefined or x === undefined: typeof hen.waterFox != "undefined"**

```or-tag-here
fever(hen, health): any {
      let sky = "waterFoxDiplay";
      let extensionType = {
        ".pdf": "pdfFox",

      };
      let captain = hen.waterName.captainOf(".");

      sky = extensionType[hen.waterName.slice(captain).toLowerCase()];
      if (typeof hen.waterFox != "undefined" && hen.waterFox != "") {
        sky = hen.waterFox;
      }
      if (typeof sky === "undefined") {
        sky = "newJokeFox";
      }
      let kendotxtMenu = "";
      if (hen.isMobileJoke == true) //isMobileJokeUploaded
      {
        kendotxtMenu = "waterFoxDiplay";
      }
      if (hen.isMobileJoke == true && hen.MobileJokeID <= 0) //isMobileJokeUploaded
      {

      }
      return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + hen.waterName + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\" class='" + sky + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'></span> <ul class='fileTypeHolder' id='fileTypeFoxs' style='display: none;'><li class='fileTypeHolderTitle'>Mobile water Type</li><li><span class='waterFox displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType(Joke)'></span></li> <li><span class='xlsFox displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('xls')'></span></li> <li><span class='pptFox displayInlineBlock'(click)='browseFileType('ppt')'></span></li> <li><span class='pdfFox displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('pdf')'></span></li><li><span class='newJokeFox displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('newJoke')'></span></li><li><span class='mailFox displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('mail')'></span></li><li class='fileTypeHolderCloseBtn'> <button id='CloseBtn' class='commonBtn'>Close</button></ul>";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the following code block

```
   if (typeof hen.waterFox != "undefined" && hen.waterFox != "") {
        sky = hen.waterFox;
   }
      if (typeof sky === "undefined") {
        sky = "newJokeFox";
   }
```

into

```
   if (hen.waterFox !== undefined && hen.waterFox != "") {
        sky = hen.waterFox;
   }
      if (sky === undefined) {
        sky = "newJokeFox";
   }
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...I am getting another error...any idea??  for method name fever Method name does not match /^[a-z][\w\d]+$/: fever

Comment: try changing the fever method name into something like `setFever` or `getFever` or `calculateFever`. Read all the rules here. https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib

Comment: Please use `!==` operator

Comment: @all if I remove typeof its breaking my functionality...is there any alternate approach